# How can i tweak this function to reduce two digits down to a single digit?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, if-statement

I have a function which takes the numbers from an input field, and sums them. However, I want the equation to continue to add the sum together until the result is a single number. I feel like I need an if statement somewhere here, but Im not sure how to write it. Could I have some suggestions for how to amend this code?

```
function getSum() {
    const input = document.getElementById('dateInput').value;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        const num = parseInt(input.charAt(i));
        if (!isNaN(num)) {
            sum += num;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = "Your life path number is: " + sum;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="cell-1"><input type="date" id="dateInput"></div>
    <div class="cell-2"><h1>Blah Blah</h1></div>
    <div class="cell-3"><input type="date" id="dateInput"></div>
    <div class="cell-4" id="result"></div>
    <div class="cell-5"><button onclick="getSum()">Calculate</button></div>
    <div class="cell-6"></div>
    <div class="cell-7"></div>
    <div class="cell-8"></div>
    <div class="cell-9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all. id should be unique. You have two input element with same id.

Comment: oh yeah woops. I need to change it to a class. It will eventually have two identical input forms as shown, which run thie code im looking for.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a `while` loop: while the calculated number is 10 or above, keep iterating and calculate a new number:

```js
const sumNumber = num => [...String(num)].reduce(
  (a, digit) => a + Number(digit),
  0
);

function getSum(input) {
  const inputNum = Number(input);
  if (Number.isNaN(inputNum)) {
    return;
  }
  let currentSum = inputNum;
  while (currentSum >= 10) {
    currentSum = sumNumber(currentSum);
  }
  console.log(currentSum);
}
getSum(15);
getSum(1234);
getSum(999999);
```

If you don't like `while` loops, you can also use recursion:

```js
const sumNumber = num => {
  const currentSum = [...String(num)].reduce(
    (a, digit) => a + Number(digit),
    0
  );
  return currentSum < 10 ? currentSum : sumNumber(currentSum);
}

function getSum(input) {
  const inputNum = Number(input);
  if (Number.isNaN(inputNum)) {
    return;
  }
  let currentSum = inputNum;
  console.log(sumNumber(inputNum));
}
getSum(15);
getSum(1234);
getSum(999999);
```

To sum up the digits, I really prefer the `reduce` method because it doesn't involve reassigning an outer variable, but you can replace it with your more manual iteration over the `charAt`s of the input string, if you're more comfortable with that, but it makes the function a lot longer and less abstract:

```js
const sumNumber = num => {
  const numStr = String(num);
  let sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < numStr.length; i++) {
    const num = parseInt(numStr.charAt(i));
    if (!isNaN(num)) {
      sum += num;
    }
  }
  return sum;
};


function getSum(input) {
  const inputNum = Number(input);
  if (Number.isNaN(inputNum)) {
    return;
  }
  let currentSum = inputNum;
  while (currentSum >= 10) {

    currentSum = sumNumber(currentSum);
  }
  console.log(currentSum);
}
getSum(15);
getSum(1234);
getSum(999999);
```

Comment: im sure this is a solid answer, but man oh man this is over my head.

Comment: I broke the function into two separate parts to (hopefully) make it easier to understand the logic - the `sumNumber` takes a number and sums it, whereas the `getSum` verifies the input and then calls / returns the call of `sumNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use replace to remove the -'s in the date, the split into an array, map through the array to parseInt, and then reduce to add them together:

```js
function getSum() {
  const input = document.getElementById('dateInput').value;
  if (input) {
    let stringThing = input.replace(/-/g, '').split('')
    let numberThing = stringThing.map(num => parseInt(num));
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = numberThing.reduce(function(acc, val) {
      return acc + val;
    })
  }
}
```